# Как сделать из типа Text в тип string в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для отправки сообщения в mail мне надо из типа Text сделать тип string.
Как это можно сделать?
Вот мой скрипт на всякий случай

```
public class Sand : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TRUE SCR;
    public Text Name;
    public Text let;
    public string SCOR;
    public string Name1;
    public string LET1;
    public void send()
    {
        SCOR = SCR.Score.ToString();
        Name1 = Name.ToString();
        LET1 = let.ToString();
        MailMessage messege = new MailMessage();
        messege.Body = let + Name1 + SCR.Score.ToString();
        messege.From = new MailAddress("alyashev.m.a@gmail.com");
        messege.To.Add("dzodzomalys@gmail.com");
        messege.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(messege.From.Address, "!");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
            { return true; };
        client.Send(messege);
    }
```

Я уже пытался сделать через ToString() но выводило это Text (UnityEngine.UI.Text)

Comment: Открываем [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html) и понимаем, что `Name1 = Name.text` будет работать. Ну и остальное по этому же принципу.  P.S. я Unity не знаю, я просто погуглил.

Comment: Кстати, то что вы делаете с `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` - это дыра в безопасности приложения размером со всё приложение. Не делайте этого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У компонента `Text` есть переменная `text`, она отвечает за весь текст в компоненте `Text`

Вот рабочий код:

```
Text name;
string name1;

void Start(){
name1 = name.text;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное